# How can I set up a DKIM DNS Record?

Tags: dns, vps, mail-server, plesk, dkim

I currently run a website, hosted on a VPS.  The software is Plesk.

I have already setup an SPF Record and a DMARC Record, via the DNS Settings.  I am a little stuck on how to set up a DKIM Record.

So far, I have gone into:

> Settings & Tools > Mail Settings > Activated DKIM

As well as activating DKIM Server wide, I have also enabled it at Domain Level.

I have identified that the DKIM Private Key is stored at: 
 `/etc/domainkeys/example.com`

I now understand that I need to enter the DKIM DNS Record, via the DNS Settings.  After browsing the web, I have read that the Public Record should be stored in `/etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/mail.txt (or default.txt)`

I have read the entry should look something like:

`v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=GHDSGGH7567KGFDBUUasd4655676vbhgvASDFsdfgh6456yh4565RFCpy4zMNWUbL6JM5XIyjBy3bUnANI5axeb/Lw/GBjUoSFLEiO80Tt8m3A5YrBKcodRQQURYiW6/YtElhLupHyfcxQhfNLU4z9JUOJKPjcpMZCj0Xv873QgVOl+7U605JdBHSPOx4ybBZwDq68cw9YFYRPmEwIDAQAB`

The problem is, I cannot find such file.  Am I missing further configuration requirements or could the Public Key be stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use DKIM on a Plesk server.

- If you only want to use DKIM for the webmail and mails sent using POP/IMAP, activating DKIM on the domainlevel in Plesk should be enough.
  (See https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002519933-How-to-enable-DKIM-support-for-a-domain)
  The DNS record should be added by Plesk automatically.
  You can verify DKIM works by sending a mail to https://dkimvalidator.com/ using the webmail or your mail client.
- However, if you also want to send DKIM signed mails from the server itself (eg a contact form on the website), you need to edit the global server settings to pass all mails through DKIM.
  While there are multiple ways to do this, installing openDKIM is the easiest. At my job, we do this automatically using configuration management, but this guide should help you on your way: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy
  *(TL;DR: install OpenDKIM, generate a key and edit your postfix to add the following milter:

  `smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:12768`,

  8891 is for openDKIM)*

You'll find the keys under `/etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/<name>.{txt,private}`
the content of the .txt file should be placed in a TXT record for **name**._domainkey.example.com. Test again from the website or the server.
(From the commandline: `mail -s 'DKIM test subject' -r 'test@example.com' xxx@dkimvalidator.com < /dev/null`)

Don't forget to double check your DMARC record, or you could potentially lose outgoing mails. (eg https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-inspector/) Maybe start with `p=none`.